# AWS- S3 Multi-Region Access point use in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Actually, I need to use the s3 multi-region feature in my c# application.

I have installed the AWSSDK dll in my project.

I have created 3 buckets with different regions like us-west-2,us-east-1, and us-east2.
and added these 3 buckets while creating the Multi-Region Access point.

After creating this Access Point, I just copied the ARN Name from the s3 multi-region board and used it in my c# code,
I just replace the bucket name with Multi-Region Access Point in My code looks like below:

```
var config=new AmazonS3Config();
config.UseArnRegion=false;
config.RegionEndPoint=RegionEndPoint.USWest2;

var s3Client=new AmazonS3Client(config);

before using multi region the code was like this and its working:
S3FileInfo info=new S3FileInfo(s3Client, "s3bucketname","Dummy.txt");

and after adding the multi region the code look like this and getting below error:
S3FileInfo info=new S3FileInfo(s3Client, "arn:aws:s3::\<account_number\>/---.mrap","Dummy.txt");

i have tried this below 2 options also but its not working getting error "The specified bucket is does not exist.."
S3FileInfo info=new S3FileInfo(s3Client, "---.mrap","Dummy.txt");
S3FileInfo info=new S3FileInfo(s3Client, "---.mrap.accesspoint.s3-global.amazonaws.com","Dummy.txt");

bool fileExist=info.Exists;

MessageBox.Show(fileExist.ToString());
```

---

I am getting errors as below:
Amazon.Runtime.AWSCommonRuntimeException: Attempting to make a request that requires an implementation of AWS Signature V4a. Add a reference to the AWSSDK.Extensions.CrtIntegration NuGet package to your project to include the AWS Signature V4a signer.

Please let me know where I am wrong. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you.

```
var mrapArn = "arn:aws:s3::{your-account-id-here}:accesspoint/{mrap-alias-here}";
string objKey = "folderA/folderB/abc.jpeg";

AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;
var client = new AmazonS3Client(new AmazonS3Config { UseArnRegion = true });

var file = await client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = mrapArn, Key = objKey });

Console.WriteLine(file.VersionId);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).